# Sum aggregation on object field

Tags: elasticsearch

Hi I have question with object aggregation.

My data is like this.

```
POST records/_doc
{
  "name": "LED TV", 
  "resellers": [
    {
      "reseller": "companyA",
      "price": 350
    },
    {
      "reseller": "companyB",
      "price": 500
    }
  ]
}

POST records/_doc
{
  "name": "LED TV", 
  "resellers": [
    {
      "reseller": "companyA",
      "price": 350
    },
    {
      "reseller": "companyC",
      "price": 500
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to use `GET _search` to get reseller's price sum.

Result will be like this.

```
companyA: 350 + 350 
companyB: 500
companyC: 500
```

Can somebody help me out in doing that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GET /products/_search?size=0
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "led tv"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "resellers": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "resellers"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sum_price": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "resellers.price"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```